# How to update a child field in Firebase using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having difficulty understanding the Firebase docs as well as the StackOverflow answers regarding using Firebase.

I have a database in Firebase that has children:

```
myDatabase:
   |
   | generatedKey1 (K####-########)
        |
        | varName1: varData1
        | varName2: varData2
   |
   | generatedKey2 (K####-########)
        |
        | varName1: varData1
        | varName2: varData2
```

What I'm trying to do is for each of these child Keys, grab the data in the variable, do some stuff to it, and then push it back into the field.  I know that the forEach method can get the information:

```
databaseRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      // stuff here
   });
});
```

And in the // stuff here, I can reference the information in the fields with childData.varName1 and childData.varName2.

But after I do my manipulation, how do I push that information back into the database?

Trying:

```
childSnapshot.update({varName1: "New data"});
```

doesn't work.

How do you reference a specific field in Firebase after it has been created and then update its info?

Answer (score 0):

**try use this example code:**

```
databaseRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
       snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          var childData = childSnapshot.val();
          var key = childSnapshot.key;
          var updateData = {varName1: "New data"}
          var updates = {};
          updates['/' + key] = updateData;
          childSnapshot.update(updates);
       });
    });
```

> ***Reference*** [Read and Write Data on the Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Comment: That seems to be working up until the childSnapshot.update(updates) line.  It dies with an error that childSnapshot.update is not a function.  It's grabbing the key correctly and is constructing the updateData object and updates array correctly, but it just won't push it back.

Comment: you try make function new for update. That does not work through function this databaseRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {}

Comment: If I change childSnapshot.update to databaseRef.update, it runs, but it starts wrecking the data in the database:  It updates the specific fields I updated but deletes all the other fields.

Any idea what's happening?  For the moment, I'm using databaseRef.update and just pushing all fields (same data for those fields that don't need to change), but surely there's a better way.  It seems that the update call is updating the entire tree for the key rather than just the field.  How to target just the single field?